# append multiple dataframes in a single df using the index position in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a multiple dataframes in the below format. 0 and 1 represents the index within a single DF in a sequential order(For example column name emp_number has length as 55 from the below sample)

```
0 Tablename
1 xyz  
0 Tablename
1 xyz

0  colName
1   emp_number  
0 colName
1 Organization_unit
   
0 ColumnLen
1 55
0 ColumnLen
1 60
```

I need the output in the following format

```
TableName  ColumnName         ColumnLen

xyz        emp_number          55
xyz        Organization_unit   45
xyz        pos_unit            60
```

I tried this code

```
      for row in df.index:
            print(row)
 for value in df.index.values:
            print(value)
```

but I am getting output as 0 and 1 only , not the actual values

I want to merge  all the DF and put in a single huge DF which can used for running SQL on the DF

My Sample input Data contains which is a result of some other process

```
data = ('tablename', 'xyz') ('tablename','xyz') ('columnname', 'emp_number')('columnname', 'Organization_unit')('columnlen', 55)('columnlen', 60)
```

post which I have added my DF like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

After which I got the out

```
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.162Z] 0       columnName
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.163Z] 1       emp_number
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.163Z]                  0
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.164Z] 0       columnName
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.164Z] 1        Organization_unit
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.217Z] 0        columnlen
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.218Z] 1             55
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.218Z]               0
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.217Z] 0        columnlen
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.218Z] 1             60
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.218Z]               0
```

and I want a dynamically generated from a DF because I dont know how many small dfs that are created as a result of previous process.

Comment: hey, could you put your data as pd.Dataframe so we can test our solution please

Comment: Before this step I had   data  =   ('tablename', 'xyz') ('tablename','xyz') ('columnname', 'emp_number')('columnname', 'Organization_unit') ('columnlen', '55') ('columnlen', '45'). After which I have put as  df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
### assuming this is your data
data = ('tablename', 'xyz'),('tablename','xyz'),('columnname', 'emp_number'),('columnname', 'Organization_unit'),('columnlen', 55),('columnlen', 60),('edge_cases','so edgy')

### create empty lists that will be your columns in your final df
TableName_list = []
ColumnName_list = [] 
ColumnLen_list = []

### iterate over tuples looking at what first element (x[0]) is 
### and checking it for values of interest and appending to corresponding lists
for x in data:
    if x[0] == 'tablename':
        TableName_list.append(x[1])
    elif x[0] == 'columnname':
        ColumnName_list.append(x[1])
    elif x[0] == 'columnlen':
        ColumnLen_list.append(x[1])

    ### check if there are some other / unexpected values and print them out
    else:
        f"you have some other data here too like this one where first element == {x[0]}"
        f"`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````"
        
### create your final dataframe from lists above
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'TableName':TableName_list,
                         'ColumnName':ColumnName_list,
                         'ColumnLen':ColumnLen_list 
                        })

final_df
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Output
[image]

Comment: thanks for the extensive explanation . I dont have a column1 for my DF . I have the last input as data = ('tablename', 'xyz') ('tablename','xyz') ('columnname', 'emp_number')('columnname', 'Organization_unit') ('columnlen', '55') ('columnlen', '45'). After which I have put as df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) . I have received the output as 2022-05-17T09:27:01.220Z] 0  columnLen
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.221Z] 1           55
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.222Z]               0
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.223Z] 0  columnlen
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.224Z] 1           60
[2022-05-17T09:27:01.225Z]               0

Comment: i dont know what your "data" type is you should create a sample of your "data" (like i did in my answer) and post with your question

Comment: I have updated the same

Comment: updated reply per updated question

Comment: I am getting output like this

Comment: you "data" object when ran actually gives an error until you input it as a bunch of tuples... so provide either screenshots or proper ways to construct your data sample right now your sample code is broken and can not be followed.. your timestamps in output dont appear in your input data either

Comment: thanks for your help, I was able to create a list and update using this solution a = {'TableName':TableName_list,'ColumnName':ColumnName_list,'ColumnLen':columnLength_list }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
f_df = df.transpose()